# How to get Javascript pop up text using Ruby 1.9.2 and Watir 1.9.1 in Windows 7 x64

Tags: ruby, watir

This link talks about how click a button but not how to retrieve the pop up text http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/JavaScript+Pop+Ups

It used to work in Ruby 1.8.6 with Watir 1.6.5 with the following code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
require 'watir/ie'
require 'watir\contrib\enabled_popup'

#get the window with specified handle.
WindowHandle = ARGV[0].to_i#1967760

if (Watir::IE.find(:hwnd,WindowHandle)==nil)
  exit(1)
else
  ObjIE = Watir::IE.find(:hwnd, WindowHandle.to_i) 
end

PopupHandle=ObjIE.enabled_popup(25)
winObj=WinClicker.new
PopupText=winObj.getStaticText_hWnd(PopupHandle).[](1)
puts(PopupText)
```

But Ruby 1.9.2 with Watir 1.9.1 does not support WinCLicker so, it is not possible to reuse the same code. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [RAutomation](http://www.itreallymatters.net/post/6791652065/viva-la-rautomation) could help.